# dynamic radiobutton and checkbox columns register events

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-3.5

I have a gridview inside a User Control which is being filled with data from a data source dynamically. One of the things I need to support is switching a non-data-bounded column from checkbox column to radiobutton column dybamically.

everything's cool when I create the columns for display, but when I try to add an event to the CheckChanged (or Click) of the columns, the events doesn't fire - Not at AsyncPostBack and not at full postback. Moreover, the AutoPostBack is set to true and the checkboxes and radiobuttons do fire the postback, but not their events.

I don't think it's relevant, but the loaded usercontrol is in a ModalPopUpExtender from AjaxToolkit and it is being showed at server side (using a dummy button, and a clickable button ith a server side event on click). Also, all the ModalPopUpExtender controls are inside of an UpdatePanel, and only the clickable button is not.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll work using Ajax and ModalPopUpExtender but I think you need to handle it in the [OnRowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event of grid.

Answer (score 0):

So, the column of the checkboxes should have been added in a static sort of way (declare the column and the checkboxes/radiobuttons in html) - the page would register to the events, or needed to be registered in PreRender of the GridView, after acknowledging that they were added during an Ajax postback... the latter is the best way... but for those who have no time to debug, first way is better. see also:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/asp-ajax-custom-controls.aspx